# How to make C# .Net web service to be permanent in IIS7?

Tags: c#, iis-7, service

I have C# .Net web service, which should be connected to some local application.
While it is connected, user can posting jobs to the local app using web methods
of this service. Once connection is established, it should last "forever" (until
server restarts :)), because there are some callback functions given to the local app,
and if service is not loaded into memory (or disconnected), local app can't make a call of callback function.

I do not know how IIS7 works, when it loads and when unloads dll of the service.
I need it not to unload service at all. How to do that?

Thank you very much,
Regards

Comment: Your web-service may need to instantiate a long-running background thread, which becomes the main portion of your application. The web service then becomes a thin layer which interacts with the background thread. Then it's OK for the web service layer to be closed & opened many times.

Comment: Yes, thank you, but they are all thing I tried to avoid. I've been thinking about it, but I hope there is somethin that would take less time for me.

Comment: Btw, MattDavey, if I do that, how should web service and the thread communicate? How the service should send message to thread what to do?

Comment: Cross-thread communication is a topic in its own right and is outside the scope of this question :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you write you web service in WCF, you can then host your service as windows service or as application, or even on normal IIS. 
WCF gives you a lot more control over you web service and how you host it.

Comment: Yes, thank you, but they are all thing I tried to avoid. I've been thinking about it, but I hope there is somethin that would take less time for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution - web service will be permanent, and so will be connection with local app, if I set application pool idle time on 0 (so IIS7 will never put it to "sleep", and unload dll of service).

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :) In future you can avoid problems like this by making sure that a web-service is just a very thin layer on top the the actual meat of the application.